# Starting teamcity 6.5 manually results in java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: teamcity, noclassdeffounderror

I try to start teamcity manually but I get an error:

```
*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jetbrains/buildServer
/agent/Check*
```

**First I stop the windows service:**

```
C:\>net stop tcbuildagent
The TeamCity Build Agent Service service is stopping..
The TeamCity Build Agent Service service was stopped successfully.
```

**Then I start the agent:**

```
C:\>C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\bin\agent.bat start
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jetbrains/buildServer
/agent/Check
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jetbrains.buildServer.agent.Check
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: jetbrains.buildServer.agent.Check.  Program will
exit.

What is causing this issue?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your installation is broken, reinstalling TeamCity and the build agent should help.

Comment: Reinstalling Teamcity and the build agent solved this issue. I have no clue what caused this problem.